# Protractor promises for getText()

Tags: javascript, protractor

I've not used protractor in a good number of months and found myself having to go back to it.  However I am failing on a really simple thing which I've had working in the past (and even used the same code to no avail.)

I have a page with the following html:

```
<label class="control-label field-required" style="">The text I want</label>
```

So I wanted to compare that this text matches another value.  So I used the following:

```
var actualText = element(by.css('label.control-label.field-required')).getText().then(function(actualText2) {
    console.log("out2    : " + actualText2);
    return expect(actualText).to.eventually.equal("hello");
});

console.log("out3    : " + actualText);
```

What I see on the console is a pass (and it shouldn't pass as the strings don't match), I see no output for "`out2`" but for "`out3`" I see :

```
out3    : ManagedPromise::194 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong - hoping someone else can.

Comment: This maybe a shot in the dark but try the same without `var actualText =`. See if your code runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from below line and should be:

```
return expect(actualText2).to.equal("hello");
// should use function argument `actualText2`, rather than outer variable `actualText`
// argument `actualText2` is not promise, so can't use `eventually` in assertion: `expect`
```

or more straight way：

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised'),
    expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

var actualText = element(by.css('label.control-label.field-required')).getText();
expect(actualText).to.eventually.equal("hello");
```

Comment: thanks for this, I had tried it your way (I think) and the code failed ( but it was a different error, so my bad for misreading it)

If I do it your way, then I do get a fail when the text doesn't match, however I don't get the nice error message showing expected and actual - what is returned for expected is "AssertionError: expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to equal 'Hello'", I tried using a toString on the expect but that showed an object - any ideas how to clarify this a little?

Comment: Did you use package `chai-as-promised`?

Comment: yes (at least the framework is configured to use it)

Comment: How about use your original way to do assertion in `then()`?  And please check whether any assertion which use `eventually` will report `AssertionError: expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to equal` if you make them fail deliberately.